# Sync data from tables in two SQL Servers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, data-synchronization

In a following app arhicecture, local C# desktop app with SQL Server Express, which need to work offline sometimes and a central web app with SQL Server Enterprise, with db per local app.

I need to sync those two databases semi-automatically, but with some controls (and info) from an local desktop and web apps. For example, I want for user to see when sync start, when it ended, etc. Also, if synced ok or there was an error. In addition, I don't need direct replication between two databases, but I need to copy some rows which belong to the client in the db table from and to the server.

What is the best solution for this problem ?

Comment: See [this answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/166556/1186), the comments below it, and the links in those comments.

Comment: Sounds like a custom [SQL Server Integration Services package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141134.aspx) is what you're looking for here.  It can manage all the *semi-automatic* sync, notifications, etc. that you're looking to accomplish.  Good luck on the the homework assignment.